# How to assert in Spock that list contains only some particular element?

Tags: groovy, guava, spock, assertion

In pure Spock/Groovy I need two separate assertions to verify that list contains some element and nothing else:

```
def "list has single element"() {
    given:
    def list = ['x']

    expect:
    list.size() == 1
    list.first() == 'x'
}
```

I can make this assertion single-line by using Guava dependency:

```
    expect:
    Iterables.getOnlyElement(list) == 'x'
```

Is there a way to do the same in single line in pure Groovy/Spock? I don't want to use Guava too much in my tests.

**EDIT**

Actually for such a simple example just `list == ['x']` is enough. I'm looking for a non Guava solution for something more complex, when multiple assertions must be performed on this single element:

```
  def "list has single element"() {
        given:
        def list = [5.0]

        expect:
        def bigDecimal = Iterables.getOnlyElement(list)
        bigDecimal.scale() == 1
        bigDecimal.precision() == 2
    }
```

Comment: How about `list == ['x']` (in groovy code)?

Comment: You can always add this method to a list.

Comment: Or, even create a `SingleElemList` implementation of the `List ` interface.

Comment: Or write a method that contains 2 asserts

Comment: The other commenters are right, of course. Their suggestions are good. But my take on this is: Tests should be readable. The two conditions in your "expect" block are readable. Just be happy with it. Why this urge for premature optimisation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If creating a helper method is acceptable, one can use `with()`:

```
def "list has single element"() {
    given:
    def list = [5.0]

    expect:
    with onlyElementOf(list), {
        it.scale() == 1
        it.precision() == 2
    }
}
```

where `onlyElementOf()` is

```
 static <T> T onlyElementOf(Iterable<T> iterable) {
    Iterator iterator = iterable.iterator()
    def first = iterator.next()
    assert !iterator.hasNext(), "Iterable has more than 1 element"
    return first
}
```

This makes the test pretty readable.